# Stop other sounds/music

Tags: java

I'm creating an application/game in java, which contains background music/sound. Everything works as expected. I want to mute/stop if some system sound/media sound/other sound playing.

Any suggestions...??

Comment: It'd be useful if you stated what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest not care about this problem - let the user decide what programs and sounds he plays in the background